# import a specific range from xls file to datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, xls

I want to import a specific range of an xls file into a datagridview. the catch is: the range changes every time, therefore I need the user to be able to select it. is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Describe how the range changes, are you sure you can't automate the selection?

Comment: You can refer to `application.selection` in Excel, but it all depends on where you started.

Comment: how does the user trigger this import to occur?

Comment: the user chooses to open a file, then the datasheet he wants, and finally the area he needs. There are absolutly no pattern in the area the user might select, it could be one row as well as it could be the full table...

Answer (score 3):

See if this code works for you. It prompts the user to open up an excel file, and then prompts them for the range they would like to see in the DataGridView. After they select the range it converts that range into a DataTable and sets the DataTable as the source.

I'm not sure how exactly you want to use it or any other features you would like to add to it, but this should give you a building block to start off of.

```
    private Excel.Application App;
    private Excel.Range rng = null;
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OFD.Filter = "Excel Worksheets|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv";
        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
            App = new Excel.Application();
            App.Visible = true;
            App.Workbooks.Open(OFD.FileName);
        }
        else { return; }

        try { rng = (Excel.Range)App.InputBox("Please select a range", "Range Selection", Type: 8); }
        catch {  } // user pressed cancel on input box

        if (rng != null) { 
            DataTable dt = ConvertRangeToDataTable();
            if (dt != null) { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; }
        }
        _Dispose();
    }
    private DataTable ConvertRangeToDataTable() {
        try {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int ColCount = rng.Columns.Count;
            int RowCount = rng.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < ColCount; i++) {
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i <= RowCount; i++) {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int j = 1; j <= ColCount; j++) { dr[j - 1] = rng.Cells[i, j].Value2; }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
    private void _Dispose() {
        try { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng); }
        catch { }
        finally { rng = null; }
        try { App.Quit(); Marshal.ReleaseComObject(App); }
        catch { }
        finally { App = null; }
    }
```