# How to import specific cells of an Excel file into datagridview using c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, oledb, windows-forms-designer

I want to import specific cells of an Excel file to specific cells of a datagridview.

I followed many tutorials here that import Excel tables, but as I want only specific cells in specific locations of the datagridview, I adapted the code.

Instead of: `DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` I did: `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dt;` but it doesn’t work.

Can anyboby help me please?

Thank you

Here is the code:

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0""";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

        //specific cell 1 - product "code"
        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [ARTIGOS$A" + textBox3.Text + ":A" + textBox3.Text + "]", con);
        //specific cell 2 - product "description"
        OleDbDataAdapter sdb = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * From [ARTIGOS$B" + textBox3.Text + ":B" + textBox3.Text + "]", con);
        //specific cell 3 - product "price"
        OleDbDataAdapter sdc = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [ARTIGOS$I" + textBox3.Text + ":I" + textBox3.Text + "]", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(dt);
        sdb.Fill(dt2);
        sdc.Fill(dt3);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dt;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = dt2;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = textBox2.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value = dt3;
```

Comment: Do you have problems to retrieve the data from the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

**Refer Following Code:**

```
private Excel.Application App;
private Excel.Range rng = null;
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
    OFD.Filter = "Excel Worksheets|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv";
    if (OFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
        App = new Excel.Application();
        App.Visible = true;
        App.Workbooks.Open(OFD.FileName);
    }
    else { return; }

    try { rng = (Excel.Range)App.InputBox("Please select a range", "Range Selection", Type: 8); }
    catch {  } // user pressed cancel on input box

    if (rng != null) { 
        DataTable dt = ConvertRangeToDataTable();
        if (dt != null) { dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; }
    }
    _Dispose();
}
private DataTable ConvertRangeToDataTable() {
    try {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        int ColCount = rng.Columns.Count;
        int RowCount = rng.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < ColCount; i++) {
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= RowCount; i++) {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int j = 1; j <= ColCount; j++) { dr[j - 1] = rng.Cells[i, j].Value2; }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
private void _Dispose() {
    try { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng); }
    catch { }
    finally { rng = null; }
    try { App.Quit(); Marshal.ReleaseComObject(App); }
    catch { }
    finally { App = null; }
}
```

Refer Following question for details about importing a specific range from xls file to gridview:

[import a specific range from xls file to datagridview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031744/import-a-specific-range-from-xls-file-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I just need to know what is wrong with this: dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dt

Comment: you are passing the object having bunch of values to single cell, dt is objct not value

Comment: but if I do: DataGridView1.DataSource = dt; it show the value of the cell, but show like a new column instead show in the place that I want, that is "dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0]"

Comment: no dude, i think you are mixing up, DataGridView1.DataSource holds bunch of data in it which stored in object dt in the form of data table. but you cant pass whole data table to cell

Comment: I'm understanding now, thanks Freelancer. But, in spite of I'm understanding now, I still do not know how to solve my problem because I am very new in c#

Comment: look, you will have to try like this: dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].toString();