# Import a specific range from CSV file to datagridview

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I copied these codes from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031744/import-a-specific-range-from-xls-file-to-datagridview-in-c-sharp) and tried it.

however, it did not work for me. Is there anything wrong with my codes or is there any other way? Or should there be anything to be improved on the codes. The codes are below.

When I have selected the range and pressed ok, nothing happens.

[Nothing will appear in  my datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFnX6.png)

```
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application App;
    private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = null;

    private System.Data.DataTable ConvertRangeToDataTable()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            int ColCount = rng.Columns.Count;
            int RowCount = rng.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < ColCount; i++)
            {
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= RowCount; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int j = 1; j <= ColCount; j++)
                {
                    dr[j + 1] = rng.Cells[i, j].Value2;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OFD.Filter = "Excel Worksheets|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv";

        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            App.Visible = true;
            App.Workbooks.Open(OFD.FileName);
        }
        else { return; }

        try
        {
            rng = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)App.InputBox("Please select a range", "Range Selection");
        }
        catch { App.Quit(); }; //user pressed cancel on input box

        if (rng != null)
        {
            System.Data.DataTable dt = ConvertRangeToDataTable();
            if (dt != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            Dispose();
        }
    }
    private void Dispose()
    {
        try { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(rng); }
        catch { }
        finally { rng = null; }
        try { App.Quit(); System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(App); }
        catch { }
        finally { App = null; }
    }
```

Comment: Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask a question. What do you mean it is not working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Didn't you ask [the very same question (deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44898267/205233) 2 or 3 days ago? Did you try placing a breakpoint on the line returning the selected range as I suggested? Please learn to use the debugger to find out what is happening.

Comment: Is `AutoGenerateColumns` true for the DGV?

Comment: @TaW it still doesn't show on the datagridview when i put on true

Comment: Are you trying to avoid getting help? Your question and answers to comments are totally terse. Things you should tell us: Are columns showing up? Are records in the DataTable? Did you use the debugger?

Comment: @TaW it still a blank datagridview ffs

Comment: @TaW rng is still null even though i pressed the range from the excel file.